# Is there a visibility problem with this initialization method?

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility

Visibility problem: When multiple threads call method handle(), is the variable redisTemplate the initialized value, or is it null in some cases?
Example here:

```
public class InnerStaticClassExample {
    private static RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    private static class Initializer {
        static {
            redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        }

        private static void init(){
        }
    }

    /**
     * Multithread concurrent call
     */
    public static void handle(String key, long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        Initializer.init();
        redisTemplate.expire(key, time, timeUnit);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of a visibility _problem_? `private` basically means visible from.the same source file only. Or are you talking about visibility from multiple threads?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When multiple threads call method handle(), is the variable redisTemplate the initialized value, or is it null due to visibility problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A small problem with your code

If you just have that code, it is probably not thread-safe if your `redisTemplate` does not contain a `volatile` modifier. This is because other code accessing `redisTemplate` could still see the `redisTemplate` being `null` **if** they have not called `Initializer.init` before. Just adding `volatile` should fix it:

```java
public class InnerStaticClassExample {
    private volatile static RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;//This is volatile

    private static class Initializer {
        static {
            redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        }

        private static void init(){
        }
    }

    /**
     * Multithread concurrent call
     */
    public static void handle(String key, long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        Initializer.init();
        redisTemplate.expire(key, time, timeUnit);
    }
}
```

#### Your code is still risky

`static` blocks are thread safe but what you are doing is a bit risky.

Normally, one would have the variable to initialize (`redisTemplate`) in the nested class and make it `private static final`. As class initialization is thread safe, this pattern would not result in unexpected behaviour.

In your case, you cannot make the variable `final` so other methods would be able to change it. You need to make sure that this is not done anywhere (except the `static` block of the nested class) because the compiler doesn't ensure that. Also make sure this is not changed in the future (neither by you nor by others).

There is a similar situation for the `init` method. While the `static` block is thread-safe, the `init` method is not. If you or somebody else puts code there (now or in the future), it will not be synchronized in any way and potentially accessed by multiple threads. It should not access unguarded state (Ideally, it should stay empty). You should not initialize the variable to initialize in `init`.

Aside from this, the variable to initialize will be `null` until you call `init` for the first time. You need to make sure to call `init` before any access to the variable to initialize. If you forget that, you might get unexpected errors that are not caught immediately.

To sum up, your way of initializing `redisTemplate` is thread-safe but that thread-safety can easily be undermined by other code.

#### Just use the standard approach

Personally, I would recommend having the variable to initialize in the nested class. This has been proved to be thread-safe, simple and performant. If you want to access `redisTemplate` without explicitly mentioning the nested class everywhere, you can add a getter.

```java
public class InnerStaticClassExample {
    private static class Initializer {
        private static final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
        static {
            redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
            //or initialize it directly 
        }
    }

    private static RedisTemplate<String, Object> getRedisTemplate(){
        //optional getter
        return Initializer.redisTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Multithread concurrent call
     */
    public static void handle(String key, long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        //with getter
        getRedisTemplate().expire(key, time, timeUnit);
        //without getter
        //Initializer.redisTemplate.expire(key, time, timeUnit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I wrote this example, I didn't realize there would be so many problems. Ha-ha. You said that this way of initializing redisTemplate is thread-safe. I have a question: Two threads call handle() at the same time, triggering the Initializer class loading, then redisTemplate is immediately visible to all threads? What's going on here to ensure its visibility?

Comment: Oh right, I didn't think of this - you need to make the variable `volatile` in order for it to be thread-safe. I have edited my answer.